# How to generate documentation of sonar qube Rules

Tags: sonarqube

we need to write our Java and PHP coding standards, and it would be great to export current rules of our Sonar Qube installation as a text format, in the way we see it on the coding rules section (with descriptions, use cases, etc).

Is there a way to export them in a readable format?

Thanks in advance,
Juan Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Reporting to export rules in Excel or whatever format you'd like using web services.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't found any widget on the Dashboard to list all rules. Is this done by a plugin? Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to the "Data Extraction" section of the page.

Comment: Shared link does not exists.